# how to avoid the type of field not be changed with create table as select command in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I found that the data type of field will be changed
when use command  such as `create table  as select * from ;`

```
C:\Users\root>sqlite3  g:\\test.db
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table test1 (day DATETIME);
sqlite> insert into  test1 (day) values(20101001);
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(test1);
0|day|DATETIME|0||0
sqlite> create table test2 as select * from test1;
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(test2);
0|day|NUM|0||0
```

the field day is DATETIME type in test1,when i use the command

```
create table test2 as select * from test1;
```

the field day type in test2 was changed into NUM type.

how can i make the field day not be changed ?how to fix ?

```
create table test2 as select * from test1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) says:

> The declared type of each column is determined by the expression affinity of the corresponding expression in the result set of the SELECT statement

In other words, the data types of the original table are not copied (in the same way as constraints, default values, or collations are not copied).

It is not possible to duplicate a table's schema with CREATE TABLE ... AS.
To do that, you have to execute the original table's CREATE TABLE statement.